# how to convert VF chart X-axis time from 24hr format to 12hr format?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I have a visualforce chart in which the time is given in 24 hours format . I want that to convert in 12 hours format with am/pm. Is there any way to achieve this .

Thanks,
Prasanth[image: A visual force chart with 24 hours time format]

```
public with sharing class CaseListController
{
public List<AggregateResult> lstCasesByDay =null;
public String Day{get; set;}
public String fromDate {get; set;}
public String toDate {get; set;}
public Integer weekDay;
public CaseList [] caseLists {get; set;}
public map<String, Integer> map1;
public Integer intCount ;
public Double NoOfCases;
public Integer HourInDay;
public Double Roundedavg;     
public  Double AvgNoOfCase{get;set;}

public PageReference fetchRecords()
{               
        Date d1  = date.parse(fromDate);
        Date d2  = date.parse(toDate);  
        map1  = new Map<String,Integer>{'Sunday'=>1,'Monday'=>2,'Tuesday'=>3,'Wednesday'=>4,'Thursday'=>5,'Friday'=>6,'Saturday'=>7};
        weekDay = map1.get(day);
        AggregateResult[] lstCasesByDay  = [select count(id), day_in_week(convertTimezone(createdDate)), hour_in_day(convertTimezone(createdDate)) from Case where CreatedDate >:d1 and CreatedDate <=:d2 and DAY_IN_WEEK(createdDate)=:weekDay group by day_in_week(convertTimezone(createdDate)),hour_in_day(convertTimezone(createdDate))  order by hour_in_day(convertTimezone(createdDate))];
        system.debug('size of lstCasesByDay: '+lstCasesByDay.size());           
        intCount = 0;
        while(d1 <= d2)
        {
            d1 = d1.addDays(1);            
            datetime myDate = datetime.newInstance(d1.year(), d1.month(), d1.day());
            if(myDate.format('EEEE') == day)
            {
                intCount++;
            }
        }
        system.debug('No of selected Day within the given date range: '+intcount);      
        Double avg  = (Double)intCount/7;       
        system.debug('avg contains: '+avg);
        Roundedavg =  avg.round();
        system.debug('roundedavg contains: '+Roundedavg);               
        caseLists =  new List<caseList>();  
        CaseList c = new CaseList();    
        if(lstCasesByDay!=null)
        {
            for (AggregateResult ar : lstCasesByDay) 
            {
                NoOfCases   = (Double) ar.get('expr0');
                HourInDay   = (Integer) ar.get('expr2');                    
                system.debug('No of caseCount: '+NoOfCases );                       
                AvgNoOfCase = NoOfCases/Roundedavg; 
                system.debug(' AvgNoOfCaseCount: '+AvgNoOfCase);                    
                c.AvgNoOfCases = AvgNoOfCase;
                c.HourInDays = HourInDay;                                                               
                caseLists.add( new CaseList(c.HourInDays,c.AvgNoOfCases));                      
            }                   
             system.debug(' caseLists:  '+caseLists);
        }
        else
        {
            system.debug('List is empty');
        }                       
        return null;    
}

public class CaseList 
{

    public Integer  HourInDays { get; private set; }        
    public  Double AvgNoOfCases{get;set;}       

    public CaseList()
    {           
    }
   public CaseList(Integer HourInDays, Double AvgNoOfCases)
    {           
        this.HourInDays = HourInDays;
        this.AvgNoOfCases = AvgNoOfCases;   
    }                   
 }
```

}

MY VF PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="CaseListController">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.QSGDatePicker, 'Main/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.QSGDatePicker,'Main/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js')}" />
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {
                new JsDatePick({
                useMode:2,
                target:"fromDate",
                dateFormat:"%m/%d/%Y",
                weekStartDay:0
             });

                new JsDatePick({
                useMode:2,
                target:"toDate",
                dateFormat:"%m/%d/%Y",
                weekStartDay:0

             });
        };
        function getDateValues()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("fromDate").value;

            var y = document.getElementById("toDate").value;

            callFetchRecords(x, y);
            //setTimeout(showGraphButton,5000);
            //showGraphButton();
        }
        /*function showGraphButton(){
            alert('');
            document.getElementById('j_id0:j_id4:j_id5:graphButton').style.display = 'block';
        }*/
        </script>

<apex:form >        
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:actionFunction name="callFetchRecords"  action="{!fetchRecords}" reRender="graphButton,d1" status="actionStatusDisplay" >
                <apex:param name="p1" assignto="{!fromDate }"  value=""/>
                <apex:param name="p2" assignto="{!toDate}"   value=""/>
        </apex:actionFunction>

       <apex:outputPanel id="d1">
              From Date: <input type ="text" id="fromDate" value="{!fromDate}"/> <br />                                        
                To Date: <input type ="text" id="toDate" value="{!toDate}"/><br />  
          Select the Day:<apex:selectList value="{!day}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                                      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Sunday" itemLabel="Sunday"/>
                                      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Monday" itemLabel="Monday"/>
                                      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Tuesday" itemLabel="Tuesday"/>
                                      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Wednesday" itemLabel="Wednesday"/>
                                      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Thursday" itemLabel="Thursday"/>
                                      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Friday" itemLabel="Friday"/>
                                      <apex:selectOption itemValue="Saturday" itemLabel="Saturday"/>
                         </apex:selectList> <br />             
                            <input type = "button"  value="FetchRecords"  onclick = "getDateValues();"/>                 
           </apex:outputPanel>

         <apex:commandButton value="Graph" id="graphButton" action="{!fetchRecords}"/> 
         <apex:actionStatus id="actionStatusDisplay" startText="loading please wait..."/>
                <apex:chart height="500" width="600" data="{!CaseLists}">
                <apex:legend position="right"/>
                    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="AvgNoOfCases" 
                        title="No Of Case" grid="true"/>
                    <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="bottom" fields="HourInDays" 
                        title="Hour In Days">
                    </apex:axis>    


        <apex:lineSeries axis="left" fill="true" xField="HourInDays" yField="AvgNoOfCases"
                    markerType="cross" markerSize="4" markerFill="#FF0000"/>
                </apex:chart>


        </apex:pageBlock>
        <div style="{!If((CaseLists.size=0),'display:block','display:none')}">
            No Records Found for the date range between {!fromDate} to {!toDate} .
        </div> 
 </apex:form>
```

Comment: How are you feeding data in the chart? in x-axis? Can you share the code?